# Doubt in proof of Herstein Theorem (Solvable Groups)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, induction, solvable-groups

I'm trying to prove this result due to Herstein (1958):

> If $G$ is a finite group and $A \le G$ is a maximal subgroup. If $A$ is abelian, then G is solvable.

Since $A$ is maximal, we have only 2 possible cases:

1. $N_G(A) = G$
2. $N_G(A) = A$

In the first case, we prove that $\dfrac{G}{A}$ is cyclic and so solvable, then $G$ is solvable, since $A$ is abelian.

In the second case, we consider two new cases:

a) There exists $x \notin A$ such that $A^x \cap A \neq 1$

b) $A^x \cap A = 1$, for all $x \notin A$

For the letter (b) we use the Frobenius Theorem, since $A$ is a Frobenius complement of $G$ and obtain the result.

In the letter (a), letting $w \in A^x \cap A$ and using that $A$ is abelian and maximal, we obtain that $w \in Z(G)$ and so $\langle w \rangle$ is a abelian normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $A$. So far so good. But at this point the author says it follows that $\dfrac{G}{\langle w \rangle}$ is solvable, arguing by induction in group order and that's what I didn't understand.

Comment: Choosing $w\ne1$, we know the order of $G/\langle w\rangle $ is less than that of $G$.

Comment: Huh? The statement you have quoted would imply every finite group is solvable. Surely you are misquoting the result in question. (Every finite group has maximal abelian subgroups; then what?) Or do you mean $A$ is maximal *and* abelian, as opposed to maximal among abelian subgroups? "maximal X subgroup" usually means maximal among X subgroups (though, granted, not always...)

Comment: The ambiguity would disappear if you said $A$ was an "abelian maximal subgroup", instead of a "maximal abelian subgroup".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in general, "maximal X group" can means either "maximal subgroup which has property X", or "subgroup which is maximal among all subgroups with property X". *Most of the time* it means the latter. (Thus, for instance, Sylow $p$-subgroups are maximal $p$-subgroups).

Here, it appears that you actually mean "maximal subgroup which is abelian", not "subgroup which is maximal among abelian subgroups". To avoid ambiguity, you should say that $A$ is "an abelian maximal subgroup", because that will be interpreted as $\text{abelian}(\text{maximal subgroup})$, i.e., a maximal subgroup which is abelian; whereas "maximal abelian subgroup" is interpreted as $\text{maximal}(\text{abelian subgroup})$, i.e., a subgroup which is maximal among abelian subgroups.

(This ambiguity would also happen in Spanish, and I suspect the same would happen in Portuguese... to describe an abelian maximal subgroup in Spanish I would say "subgrupo maximal abeliano", whereas a maximal abelian subgroup would be a "subgroup abeliano maximal", which could lead to the mistranslation because of the reverse word order...)

---

On to the substance of your question:

This is a pretty standard argument, though it is not explicitly phrased as an induction.

We proceed by induction on $|G|$. Assume that $|G|=n$, and that for all subgroups $\mathfrak{G}$ with $|\mathfrak{G}|\lt n$, if $\mathfrak{G}$ has an abelian maximal subgroup, then $\mathfrak{G}$ is solvable.

In your final situation, you have a nontrivial subgroup $\langle w\rangle\leq Z(G)$; let $\mathfrak{G}=G/\langle w\rangle$. Then $|\mathfrak{G}|\lt n$; moreover, $A/\langle w\rangle$ is a maximal subgroup of $\mathfrak{G}$, and since $A/\langle w\rangle$ is a quotient of an abelian group, it is abelian. Thus, $\mathfrak{G}$ has an abelian maximal subgroup. By the induction hypothesis, $\mathfrak{G}$ is solvable.

But then $\langle w\rangle$ is abelian, and $G/\langle w\rangle$ is solvable, therefore $G$ is solvable as well. QED

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understood! 

Ps: Thanks also for what you said above, my english level is still very basic

Comment: I just gave a reference to an identical question (I found it almost at once by "googling" the title of the present question !).